# notification/alert options in symbian OS

Tags: java-me, symbian, nokia

I'm trying to figure out whether or not I can register/call notifications in the symbian OS that's fit for the S60 series, using an app, that interrupt the OS and appear on the dashboard screen, the same way incoming calls and text messages do.
If so, is it just a basic alert, or can it contain a context menu (on either side) with options relating to the app?

I appreciate any help on this issue, as it'll determine whether the app is even feasible at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pop up something on top of the home screen, that is perfectly feasible - a Window in a WindowGroup with the right priority will do (I've done this before). As such, this could have a menu, or whatever you need.

You don't say what events you need to hook on to when displaying this screen?